# Trying to extract attribute values using Nokogiri with custom pseudoclass CSS selectors

Tags: html, css, ruby, css-selectors, nokogiri

Having loaded a (X)HTML page, I'm trying to get the value of a meta tag's "content" attribute. For example, given:

```
<meta name="author" content="John Smith" />
```

I'd like to extract the value "John Smith".

I know how to do that using XPath and understand that CSS was meant primarily for element selection but Nokogiri supports defining [custom CSS pseudoclasses](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-css) which I thought could be used as follows:

```
class CSSext
  def attr(nodeset, tag)
    nodeset.first.attribute_nodes.find_all {|node| node.name == tag}
  end
end

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(someurl))
doc.css("meta[name='name']:attr('content')", CSSext.new)
```

However, this returns the same result as

```
doc.css("meta[name='name']")
```

What gives? Nokogiri uses the same engine underneath for both CSS and XPath searches so anything that's possible in XPath should be doable in CSS. How should I go about extracting the attribute value?

Comment: Why don't you take the simple path and use `doc.css("meta[name='name']")`? CSS in Nokogiri is a very usable substitute for XPath in any Node lookup. Do the simpler thing, which makes it easier to and understand and maintain.

Comment: @Scott Roepnack: That's not [an appropriate use of backticks](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code-spans) for formatting. Notice also that you've caused the link Markdown to break as well...

Answer (score 7):

Why not just?

```
doc.at("meta[name='author']")['content']
```

As far as I understand, pseudoclasses can be used to filter the nodeset only, but not to replace the nodeset with some other value such as the value of one of the nodes's attribute.